# How to implement cancellation in Request Reply Pattern in .NET?

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, design-patterns, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I am trying to implement a Job Scheduling Program that uses Azure Service Bus and Azure Functions.

I am trying to use request reply pattern for the same.

After implementing the Job Start and Job Status APIs I am stuck on Job Cancel API.

What are the are possible solutions to cancellation of consumer Jobs already started. (In this case Functions triggered from Azure Service Bus)

One solution I am able to think of is that consumers monitor the job-request-status (Scheduled/ Completed / Aborted / CancellationRequested) set by cancel api that sets the flag for the specific job.

Any better solutions involving use CancellationToken or any other best practices / patterns?

References :
https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/RequestReply.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/async-request-reply

[image]

Comments on Backend implementation of this kind of APIs.

[image]

---

### Update : 13-Jan-2023

Tried using Azure Durable function.

Tried terminating the task using the link provided but one limitation i see is the task in execution still completes.

Explained :

If orchestration creates 3 tasks (T1, T2, T3) of 60 seconds each in chaining pattern. If we cancel when T1 has 30 seconds elapsed on it, then cancellation will go in effect after current task is completed. That is T1 will be still completed. T2 T3 will not start.

[image]

Comment: So how does your function look like? You have a service bus triggered function that kicks off a long running durable workflow, is that it? What are the steps involved?

Comment: Yes a function app that starts running some simulation. But if user decides to change some input to that simulation then the user will trigger a cancellation. That needs to terminate the already running job.

Comment: Does the job support cancellation? Do you have any code to share?

Comment: The job can take the cancellation token if required. The code i have does not stop the already running job instead it stops the consequent job that are queued  in the orchestrating function.

Comment: Without code it is hard to give concrete help

Answer (score 0):

The task you are running should take the cancellation token as a parameter and internally should check if the cancellation was requested. Just 'activating' the token will not automatically stop the running task(s). Task should either check `token.IsCancellationRequested` property and break if it's set or call `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` which will throw an exception to break the running task.

```cs
void Run1(CancellationToken token)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // Cleanup if necessary.
            // Terminate the operation.
            break;
         }

         // Do the piece of actual work.
         ...
    }
}
```

or

```cs
void Run2(CancellationToken token)
{
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()

            // Do the piece of actual work.
            ...
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
    {
        // Cleanup if necessary.
        // Terminate the operation.
    }
}
```

See [Cancellation in Managed Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads) for details.

Comment: Will not work when the task is invoked using Service Bus Trigger since the token is not set on the task executing machine by caller code.